# Scrapy only show the first result of each page

Tags: scrapy

I need to scrape the items of the first page and then go to the next button to go to the second page and scrape and so on.

This is my code, but only scrape the first item of each page, if there are 20 pages enter to every page and scrape only the first item.

Could anyone please help me .

Thank you

Apologies for my english.

```
class CcceSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'ccce'
item_count = 0
allowed_domain = ['www.example.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.example.com./afiliados value=&categoria=444&letter=']

rules = {
    # Reglas Para cada item
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = (), restrict_xpaths = ('//li[@class="pager-next"]/a')), callback = 'parse_item', follow = True),
}

def parse_item(self, response):
    ml_item = CcceItem()
    #info de producto
    ml_item['nombre'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="news-col2"]/h2/text())').extract()
    ml_item['url'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="website"]/a/text())').extract()
    ml_item['correo'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="email"]/a/text())').extract()
    ml_item['descripcion'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="news-col4"]/text())').extract()


    self.item_count += 1
    if self.item_count > 5:
        #insert_table(ml_item)
        raise CloseSpider('item_exceeded')  
    yield ml_item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't given an working target url, I'm a bit guessing here, but most probably this is the problem:

**`parse_item` should be a `parse_page`** (and act accordingly)

Scrapy is downloading a full page which has - according to your description - multiple items and then passes this as a response object to your parse method.

It's your parse method's responsibility to process the whole page by iterating over the items displayed on the page and creating multiple scraped items accordingly.

The scrapy documentation has several good examples for this, one is here: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths

Basically your code structure in `def parse_XYZ` should look like this:

```
def parse_page(self, response):
    items_on_page = response.xpath('//...')
    for sel_item in items_on_page:
        ml_item = CcceItem()
        #info de producto
        ml_item['nombre'] = # ...
        # ...
        yield ml_item
```

Insert the right xpaths for getting all items on the page and adjust your item xpaths and you're ready to go.

Comment: Thank you, you're a genius.